# Fluorometer for measuring fluorescence in a sheet of water

Tags: fluorescence

Does anyone know of a fluorometer that I could use to measure fluorescence in a thin sheet of water.  So it would be like holding a piece of writing or printer paper vertically and trying to get a reading of the fluorescence at various locations around an 8.5 by 11 area of the paper sheet (although the sheet of water won't be nearly that big - more like 3x5).  A small probe so that multiple locations could be measured by simply moving the probe would be great. A submersible probe would not be good as it would disrupt the sheet.  The sheet will contain quinine at varying amounts depending upon how far a quenching reaction with chloride ion has progressed.

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know of a fluorometer, per se, that would directly do what you want. But the fluorescence maximum is about 460 nm, so a glass or plastic fiber optic, photodiode, transimpedance amplifier and ADC (assuming digital output is required) would work fine. One end of the fiber optic would be movable and placed wherever needed and the other would go directly to the photodiode. You would also need a non-fluorescent long pass optical filter to avoid the excitation light reaching the photodiode. Sounds like a nice project: best of success with it!

Comment: Thanks Ed V.    I have never used a fluorometer.  Can you get me started?

Comment: Do you know the units associated with your length? 8.5 x 11 ad 3 x 5 ? If you take pictures of your sheet with a right cut-off filter in front of your camera, you may use Image-J with light intensity. You will have to illuminate uniformly.

Comment: @M. Farooq:  The lengths I quoted were for illustration only; they were in inches.  The sheet will have different lengths depending upon velocity and nozzle size.  I never heard of ImageJ.  I googled it and it looks like it is a Java-based image processing program.  I'm trying to figure out what it does and how it can help me get quantitative readings of either fluorescence or color.

Comment: Thanks, Ed!  M. Farooq's idea has a certain simplicity to it (for me at least), so I'll probably give that a try, first. So, will any blacklight from Amazon work, or do I need to try and find something that is about 460 nm?  For uniformity of lighting, I would buy something that has the UV lamps in a rectangular enclosure that is significantly larger than the sheet - something like a floodlight.  Does this seem a reasonable approach?

Comment: As I state [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130758/79678), the optimum excitation wavelength is about 365 nm, i.e., near UV or so-called “long wave UV”. The peak emission wavelength is 460 nm. A blacklight should work well, assuming uniform illumination. I would try that.

Comment: @rdemyan Please be careful with UV light. It can harm your skin and eyes if not used properly. Do you have an academic supervisor who is guiding you? What is this project about?

Comment: Silly idea: Switch on UV, take photo, switch off. Build a nice cardboard box so that sheet and light are always in the right place, with a hole on the top to put your camera/phone on. Use ImageJ to evaluate the picture, or Matlab/Octave, gnuplot, ...

Comment: @Karl Good idea, actually, especially given the OP’s stated experience level. Minor variant: record a video and use simple frame grabbing software/app. Then time evolution is easy to see, etc.

Comment: @M.Farooq:  I had an advisor 30+ years ago :). The plan is to focus the camera without the UV light on and then once it is focused, turn on the UV light and take a few pictures.  Then turn off the light and examine the pictures on a large screen. If not good, repeat, otherwise change the pressure drop and take more pictures. I have goggles that provide UV400 protection.  But I didn't really consider the skin too much, so I'll add in some precautions (like maybe a face shield and gloves).  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @rdemyan, This is a problem with anonymous public forums. We have no idea whether the OP is a teenager, adult or a very experienced person. In any case, the context is missing as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Ed V.  I'm not sure video will work, because the whole process will be at a steady state.  If the video sees the whole sheet, I think every frame will look the same during this steady state process.  So if the fluorescence disappears after 1 cm of flow, that's pretty much what will always be seen while conducting a run. Digital photography should work better.  To get sharp lines, I guess I will want to reduce the shutter speed substantially.  It will be interesting to see how low I can set the value (with respect to ISO and F stop).

Comment: @M. Faroog:  I appreciate your replies.  The Image-J idea sounds intriguing and could be exactly what I need.  However, I suspect I will need to do a fair amount of calibration work. I hope there will be some leeway with respect to the distance the UV light source is from the sheets.  Unfortunately, I have to take down my equipment after every session. So the UV light will have to be mounted every time.  I will measure the distance between source and sheets and try to keep that as constant as possible.  I'll have to make some standardize solutions of quinin for calibration, I think.

Comment: Forget about skin protection. You're not going to have your hand under there for more than a minute at a time, are you? I personally also woudn't bother with UV safety glasses, make sure the lamp is mounted in a way nobody can look directly into it. Build a cardboard box for it.

Comment: @M. Farooq:  I've googled "right cut off filter" but can't seem to find what it is or means. Is this used with regular light to get just the UV into the camera.  Is it used in addition to a UV source such as a black light?

Comment: @rdemyan, I have no idea of cameras and their filters but a cut-off filter is a generic term in optics.  Search Edmund Optics. https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/optics/optical-filters/

Comment: @M. Farooq:  I've been investigating Image-J and even left a rather long post at the main help forum.  My biggest question right now is how to determine the concentration of quinine.  I will know the quinine concentration in the sheet that contains quinine and acid.  Once that sheet impinges with the aq. chloride sheet, quenching will start to occur.  I'll be able to get pixel readings from the photographs, but I'm not sure how I convert those readings into concentrations of quinine.

Comment: @M. Farooq: Also, if I get a reading of say 100 and areas of the photograph that are black and not part of the sheets have a reading of 25 (so a background reading if you will since these areas have no fluorescence), would I need to subtract the background reading from the 100 reading yielding a value of 75.  Or how do I account for the fact that the lowest possible reading is 25 and not zero.  Thanks!

Comment: @rdemyan, What you are trying to do is a non-trivial exercise which may require some time to optimize. I have never done this type of flow analysis on a sheet. Until and unless your post is clear, with schematics, with all experimental variables no reader can make any suggestion. This also means you explain the purpose of this experiment. Quinine quenching by chloride follows a named law, which I am forgetting now.

Comment: Hi M. Farooq.  I have posted a pretty detailed discussion of the issues along with a fluorescence photo from 30 years ago (using coumaric acid).  It doesn't seem to me that this forum is the place to post such a detailed post (but maybe I'm wrong).  Anyway, if you get the chance and have any interest, the post is located at forum.image.sc.   Just enter "impinging" into the search box and the post will appear.  Thanks for any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: Well, I tried using quinine and spraying it out into a thin liquid sheet.  No difference in fluorescence relative to spraying water only was detected.  Based on literature I tried using 2 liters of tonic water diluted about ten times.  This would give a concentration of less than 10 ppm. Sulfuric acid was added to the tank to provide a molarity of 0.05.  No fluorescence was observed in the sheet, although a little could be observed in the edges of the sheet which are significantly thicker due to surface tension. I used a 365 nm UV light for excitation.  Comment continued below.

Comment: I'm guessing I need a much higher concentration of quinine.  Quinine is quite expensive when dealing with liters per minute of flowrate.  I guess I'll try fluorescein instead unless someone can point to something I'm not doing correctly.  For fluorescein it looks like I should get a UV light source with a longer wavelength.