# Can excited electronic states also decay due to collisions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I was wondering if electronic states could decay due to collisions and not by fluorescence?

Just like vibronic relaxations can happen, when vibrationally excited molecules can lose those extra modes of vibration by collision with solvent particles, so the vibrational energy gets converted to translational energy of the solvent molecules. But is something like this also possible for electronic transitions or is this limited because of the short half-life of those electronically excited states?

Comment: Half-life is not necessarily short here.

Comment: A He-Ne laser uses collisional relaxation to get Ne back to the ground state.

Comment: Absolutely! Look at the fluorescence of quinine in tonic water here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130758/79678. Adding ordinary table salt quenches the fluorescence: the chloride ions are the culprits. Collisional quenching of fluorescence is common and well known.

Comment: BTW, the reverse can occur, where collisions *trigger* dropping from a metastable state, emitting radiation. Thermoluminescence is useful for dating pottery and igneous rocks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoluminescence

Comment: Yes, there are 3 main mechanisms, energy transfer (Forster  & Dexter type) which needs only close approach of molecules, electron transfer, usually v close range and spin orbit coupling by heavy atoms/ions (heavy atom effect), as mentioned above by Ed V, also close range. Collisions by solvent do not generally cause deactivation unless by one of these mechanisms, but does take heat away after reaction.